# How to send a veriable in a string to server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, client-server

I am communicating to a server on socket via TCP connection in an iPhone application. I have two text fields `uTextField` (for Username) & `pTextField` (for password) and now I want to send this request to the server. can any body tell me how can I pass the value of my text fields?
here plz check my code:

```
UInt8 message[] = "LOGN|rms01,123456|<END>";
                CFDataRef data = CFDataCreate(NULL, message, sizeof(message));
                CFSocketSendData(s, NULL, data, 0);
                CFRelease(data);
                NSLog(@"msg sent");
```

Note: My code is working good as it is, issue is to pass the values of my text fields instead of hard code. here `rms01` is username and `123456` is a password LOGN is login identifier &  to tell server that query end.

I know this is a stupid question but I am new in iPhone development so please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSString can do most of the work for you with `stringWithFormat:` and `dataUsingEncoding:`:

```
NSString *username = @"username";
NSString *password = @"password";

NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LOGN|%@,%@|<END>", username, password];
CFDataRef messageData = (CFDataRef)[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

CFSocketSendData(s, NULL, messageData, 0);
```

Note that you do not need to release `messageData`.

Comment: oh thanx thank u so much thats the exactly that i want.
it is working perfectly :-)